# Publish an image with text on facebook

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I would like to post a feed on facebook by using fallback share. It should contain an image and a message. I have tried soo much by changing the params

```
 NSMutableDictionary *postParams =
[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
 @"http://www.abc.com",@"link",
 self.produtObj.productImageURL, @"picture",
 self.produtObj.productName, @"name",
 self.produtObj.productDescription, @"message",
 nil];

[FBRequestConnection
 startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
 parameters:postParams
 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                     id result,
                     NSError *error) {
     NSString *alertText;
     if (error) {
         alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                      error.domain, error.code];
     } else {
         alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"Posted action, id: %@",
                      [result objectForKey:@"id"]];
     }
     // Show the result in an alert
     [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                 message:alertText
                                delegate:self
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                       otherButtonTitles:nil]
      show];
 }];
```

With this code, the feed is displayed in a box and clicking on it is taking me to the link spcified. I just want to have an image thumbnail with the story for it not inside the box. Please help me. This is my first question in SOF. So please forgive me for my mistakes.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I found that the words i should have used are, an Image With its description. But the whole text should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really prefer to use the UIActivityItemViewConroller for pushing stuff up to facebook.

The user needs to be logged into facebook on their device.  You can do that through settings in the Facebook section.

I make the new controller like this for my stuff:

```
    NSMutableArray *stuff = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *textstring = @"Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country. Lorum Ipsum etc";
    UIImage *pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-Small-50"];//A local image
    NSString *URL = @"http://nwc.co/images/nwc-icon-200.gif";//A link to an image
    [stuff addObject:textstring];
    [stuff addObject:pic];
    [stuff addObject:URL];
    UIActivityViewController *vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:stuff applicationActivities:nil];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
        //do something here when they are done   
    }];
```

If you run the above, you'll notice that the text, the local image, and a link to the online image all appear on the post.
And you can exclude other activities, if you don't want to confuse people when the activity icons pop up:

```
vc.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This was a new information for me. I didnt know about this facility. The story was published exactly how i wanted. But, in the app, i would like to set the text un-changeable and the user to just add his message for the share. Iam new to this. So can you tell me if it is possible?

Comment: You can't send an NSString or HTML string or any other such thing that populates with a facebook post that the user can't edit.  So if you want to send an "add" about your app that can't be changed, you just need to send along a jpg or other image that has your little advertisement in it.  You can brand better, with an embedded logo and specific font any way.  JPG's can be pretty small too.  You see these a lot, like "Jimmy just won a prize in farmville" and then you see a jpg of a cow or some such thing.

Comment: Ok, thankyou for your response. Actually i was looking for something like how we get when we share a news in bbc page. you will get the image, Description and above our message will be displayed. i thought it would be possible. Thankyou for your time and a very nice explanation.